# Is there errata for this misleading side-quest hook regarding Orolunga?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tomb-of-annihilation, errata, plot-hooks

In *Tomb of Annihilation* there's this adventure hook on p. 17, under ["Side Quests"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/port-nyanzaru#SideQuests):

> in Port Nyanzaru an acolyte stumbles up to the PC and says, "Speak to the wise guardian of Orolunga, **east** of Mbala. She can direct you to that which you seek" (emphasis mine).

However, the hook is misleading:

> on the [map of Chult](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/the-land-of-chult#Map21Chult) on p. 39, Orolunga is **west** of Mbala.

Has errata been published for this? Or is this information incorrect on purpose, perhaps part of a pattern of misleading clues in *Tomb*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Nope, there is no direct follow up. It is just a way to guide players towards Orolunga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This hasn't been errataed yet or explained by the designers, so the reason for the discrepancy is unclear.

As you note, #10 under the ["Side Quests"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/port-nyanzaru#SideQuests) section (ToA, p. 17) has an NPC tell the party to find someone at Orolunga, "east of Mbala" - even though the [map of Chult](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/the-land-of-chult#Map21Chult) (p. 39) shows Orolunga as west of Mbala. However, no explanation has been given for this discrepancy, either in the adventure or in a designer statement.

[*Tomb of Annihilation* was updated in June 2020](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/rules-game-mechanics/8760-official-wizards-of-the-coast-errata?comment=17) (a month after this question was asked), as of the 6th printing of the adventure, to remove some offensive content and correct a few minor errors. It was updated again in 2021 to change some other phrasing, but the [2021 errata PDF for ToA](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/ToA-Errata.pdf) still doesn't indicate that this apparent error in side quest #10 has been corrected.

As such, it's impossible to know for sure what the reason for this difference is unless it is fixed in a future errata (which would indicate that the NPC was not meant to mislead the party, and that it was just a typo) or unless a designer makes a statement addressing/explaining the issue.

---

A number of users have wondered exactly the same thing as you in [this 2018 /r/dndnext thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/95tkbk/toa_errata_assistance_seek_wisdom_at_orolunga/) and [this 2020 /r/TombofAnnihilation thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tombofannihilation/comments/ejewpt/speak_to_the_wise_guardian_of_orolunga_east_of/), but there doesn't seem to be an overall consensus on why the NPC wrongly describes the location of Orolunga (though "typo" seems more likely).

[A 2017 D&D Beyond forum post](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/8828-toa-possible-typo-issue) also notes that both the DDB version and the physical version of the adventure contain this inaccurate phrasing, and asks if DDB can fix it; a DDB mod responded that DDB has to replicate the physical version of the adventure, which means that the possible typo won't be fixed unless/until Wizards of the Coast makes that change in the physical book as well.

Answer (score 0):

## It's possible that the NPC is making a mistake about the location of Orolunga.

It's worth pointing out they the incorrect information isn't being given by the omniscient perspective of the Main text, but by the dialogue of an NPC. The NPC is a person, they can make mistakes. Maybe they just got confused about where Orolunga was located, or mixed up east and west. It's not like they're reading a map when they're giving the directions, right?